# css bordered navigation bar with React

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am a backend dev doing front end now, anyways I am in need to create a bordered nav bar that looks as the following.

I tried to get this to work but never got the needed result.
Could you please point me out ?
Thank you

**Nav Bar Design:**

[image: Design]

EDIT: due to my stupidity I will rephrase.

What I need is a toggle with 3 items:

ITEM A | ITEM B| ITEM C

thank you

Comment: Can you please update your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.nav-container{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #2B82B3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item:hover{
  color: white;
  background-color: #2B82B3;
}

.spacer{
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #2B82B3;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    Text<br />
    text
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i forgot to mention that the white ones are also Items that will follow the same structure as in the middle, there must be a border between them that is horizintal  ITEM A | ITEM B | ITEM C and when hovering on one, it turns blue with white text, usually its black.

Comment: @user2814139 usually, we want to see what you already tried, and not give you the solution. Next time, please add your code and we'll see what didn't work and guide you how to solve the problem.